# Cannot implicitly convert type 'int' to 'char' while using Aggregate Extension method

Tags: c#, lambda

Trying to reverse a string but getting error in Aggregate function

```
private string Reverse(string strValue)
        {

            char[] chArray = strValue.ToCharArray();
            var reverse = chArray.Reverse();

            var res = reverse.Aggregate((a,b)=>a+b);

            return res.ToString();
        }
```

**Cannot implicitly convert type 'int' to 'char'. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)**
So what is the mistake?

Comment: Why are you aggregating it like that? I don't get it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Exactly as it says: the result of `a + b` is an `int`, but you want it to be a `char`. To get it to *compile* you can just use:

```
var res = reverse.Aggregate((a,b)=>(char) (a+b));
```

... but I don't think that will do what you want it to.

I suggest you don't use LINQ for this to start with:

```
private string Reverse(string strValue)
{
    char[] chArray = strValue.ToCharArray();
    Array.Reverse(chArray);
    return new string(chArray);
}
```

Note that this *doesn't* work properly with things like combining characters, surrogate pairs etc.

If you really wanted to use LINQ, you could do it with:

```
private string Reverse(string strValue)
{
    return new string(strValue.Reverse().ToArray());
}
```

There's no need to call `Aggregate`. If you *really* want to make it slow and use string concatenation with `Aggregate` (it'll be O(n<sup>2</sup>)) you can do it like this:

```
private string Reverse(string strValue)
{
    return strValue.Reverse().Aggregate("", (str, c) => str + c);
}
```

Here's we've provided a string seed value, so the parameter `str` will be a string and `+` will be string concatenation, not character *addition*.

You can make it more efficient using `StringBuilder`:

```
private string Reverse(string strValue)
{
    return strValue.Reverse()
                   .Aggregate(new StringBuilder(), (sb, c) => sb.Append(c))
                   .ToString();
}
```

... but I'm still not sure it's worth it...

Comment: Then cannot we use to Aggregate here to merge the string

Comment: I liked your StringBuilder with Aggregate approach.

Answer (score 2):

You have to use another overload of Aggregate to specify the return type string by using a seed value:

```
var res = reverse.Aggregate("", (a, b) => a + b);
```